# I'm having troubles getting drop-down-menus in MVC to return data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, drop-down-menu

I am very new to MVC as a whole, and I was sent to create a web application that would give the user options then change the view based on these options.  First I created a simple "select" html drop down menu but I am under the assumption that this won't work.
     I can supply all the actual code I currently have, I just don't know what would be important to see and what would just be bothersome to wade through. 
     When I had created a constructor for the model, it wouldn't go through that constructor or else it would be easier. 
    Sorry since this all sounds probably bad, but any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple ways to do that , here's what i do :

create the function in your controller (The one that returns the list of items you want to include in the dropdownmenu) . let's name it getNames();
Then return that to the view using @viwbag.Names;

In the view you can declare a variable , something like:

```
@{
SelectListItem[] Names = ViewBag.Name;
}
```

and the dropdown menu code should be something like this:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("Names", Names)
```

Finally, here is sample code for the controller:

```
 IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Names =
        (from names in YourDB.students.ToArray()
         select new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = names.Name,
             Value = names.Id
         }).ToArray();
       var Templist = names.ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = Templist.ToArray();
```